# Search through XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am very beginner to PHP. I have a XML file. I want to search for a node with `name` attribute value, and to store its child node's text values into variables. How can I do it with PHP code.

Example.

> `<Server>`
>         `<Server1>`
>                `<ipaddress name="10.3.0.5">`
>                            `<username>user</username>`
>                            `<password>password</password>`
>                `</ipaddress>`
>         `</Server1>`
>   `</Server>`

This is the XML file I am having.The parent node `<Server>` in this XML file will contain many `<Server1>` child nodes.Here, I want to get datas inside nodes `<username>` (user) and `<password>` (password) into two different variables when search with keyword `10.3.0.5` (which is `id` attribute value of node `ipaddress`). Please Help me with a nice PHP code for this.

Comment: You need a PHP XML Parser

Comment: Read the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699821/php-check-if-xml-node-exists-with-attribute

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by restating your question as I understood it: If you have several children of the server-element, which themselves each have a child identified by ip addresses, how could you pull out the username and password for a given ip address?

If that was indeed your question, I believe the solution below could work for you:

```
<?php

// Declare which ip address you want to get more information about
$ip_address_to_find = '10.3.0.5';

// Full xml string that you need to search through (this is an imagined example. The last element in this xml is the one we're going to find)
$xml_string = '
<Server>
      <Server1>
             <ipaddress name="10.3.0.1">
                         <username>username1</username>
                         <password>password1</password>
             </ipaddress>
      </Server1>
      <Server2>
             <ipaddress name="10.3.0.2">
                         <username>username2</username>
                         <password>password2</password>
             </ipaddress>
      </Server2>
      <Server3>
             <ipaddress name="10.3.0.3">
                         <username>username3</username>
                         <password>password3</password>
             </ipaddress>
      </Server3>
      <Server4>
             <ipaddress name="10.3.0.4">
                         <username>username4</username>
                         <password>password4</password>
             </ipaddress>
      </Server4>
      <Server5>
             <ipaddress name="10.3.0.5">
                         <username>username5</username>
                         <password>password5</password>
             </ipaddress>
      </Server5>
</Server>';

// Use simplexml to make an object out of it
$xml_object = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

// Cycle through the object until you find a match
foreach($xml_object as $server){
    if($server->ipaddress->attributes()->name == $ip_address_to_find ){
        $username = $server->ipaddress->username;
        $password = $server->ipaddress->password;
        // Now use $username and $password however you want
        // for example:
        echo 'For the server with IP address: '.$ip_address_to_find.', the username is: '.$username.', and the password is: '.$password.'.'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: But I am having a separate XML file.

Comment: then you just use file_get_contents or curl, or whatever way you wanna retrieve the xml. It still ends up as a string, assigned to a variable, at which point you can search through it as I've indicated above.